# Is the set $x^2>2$, $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the set $S=\{x^2>2$, $x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$? I think yes. My argument: Define open as usual in a metric space. It is clear that $S$ is open. Define closed by limit points. Then $S$ contains all its limit points ($\pm \sqrt{2}$ are not in $\mathbb{Q}$). So it is also closed. Besides, being a metric space, one can equivalently define closed sets as the complement of open sets. Then because $\{x^2<2$, $x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is open, $S$ is closed.

Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even have to use limits. $x^{2}>2\Leftrightarrow |x|>\sqrt{2}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ "$x>\sqrt{2}$ or $x<-\sqrt{2}$". So $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x^{2}>2\}$ $=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x>\sqrt{2}\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x<-\sqrt{2}\}$ $=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x\geq\sqrt{2}\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x\leq-\sqrt{2}\}$

(The first union is written to be open and the second is written to be closed).

Comment: Or, you could just let me fix my own TeX. The answer was correct. I was just trying to get the formatting right. (which is tricky on a phone)

Comment: And I can't see it like your suggesting when on a mobile. That was the issue.

Comment: I'm sure Marc didn't mean to be so rude.

Comment: I was also being rude. And I sincerely apologize. ...I was just so danged frustrated by my phone. Haha

Comment: No offence intended. I sympathise with those having to bear the yoke of mobile phones...

Comment: @Michael Cotton. So does my arguments apply to argue that the single interval $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x>\sqrt{2}\}$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen They should add a LateX keyboard as part of the Stackexchange app, I think....

Comment: Oh. That may be part of my problem. I haven't been using the app.

Comment: @Kyson   Yeah, it works. In fact, you should be able to show that any interval with irrational endpoints becomes clopen when you restrict to the rationals. That's a small step from what you've got. But the next challenge is: Take a closed interval that has rational endpoints. Does it become open?

Comment: @Michael Cotton. For an interval with rational endpoints included, I think it is easy to see that it cannot be open, as neighborhoods of the two end points always contain rational numbers outside the interval.

Comment: @Kyson  Nicely done! I actually almost missed that observation when I first commented back to you. Haha

Comment: @Kyson  And by complements that also says that open intervals with rational endpoints do not become closed.